# PL/pgSQL syntax error: 42601

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm quite new to pl/pgsql and I have one issue: I'm trying to create function that will calculate tax based on `pensja` in:

```
create table pracownicy (
  id_pracownika int unique
, imie varchar(20)
, nazwisko varchar(20)
, miasto varchar(20)
, pensja real);

insert into pracownicy values
  (1, 'John', 'Smith', 'New York', 150)
, (2, 'Ben', 'Johnson', 'New York', 250)
, (3, 'Louis', 'Armstrong', 'New Orleans', 75)
, (4, 'John', 'Lennon', 'London', 300)
, (5, 'Peter', 'Gabriel', 'London', 100);
```

I've created function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pit(pensja real)
  RETURNS real AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    dochod REAL;
    podatek REAL;
BEGIN
    dochod = 12*pensja;
      IF dochod <= 85528 THEN
         podatek = dochod*0,18-556,02;
         RETURN podatek;
ELSE
      podatek = 14839 + 0,32*(dochod - 85528);
      RETURN podatek;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'm trying to run it with:

```
select nazwisko, pensja, pit(pensja) from pracownicy;
```

Receiving:

> ```
> ERROR: query "SELECT * dochod 0,18-556,02" returned 3 columns
> SQL state: 42601
> Context: function PL / pgSQL pit (real), line 8 in the assignment
> ```

And I'm not quite sure where the error is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use a dot as decimal separator:

```
  podatek = dochod*0.18-556.02;
```

Comment: And a link to the description of a DECIMAL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-DECIMAL

Comment: heh, I didn't see that coming ;) Thanks

Comment: just want to add that using comma sepeartor isntead of  dot separator, totally changes the view of the sql enginne of the expression, which 'thinks' you are returning 3 columns instead of one, because the column separator is `,`. The error you recieve shows it: ERROR: query `"SELECT * dochod 0,18-556,02"` returned 3 columns - `dochod 0` - first column, `18-556` - second column, `02` - third column

Answer (score 0):

Besides the primary issue with the decimal separator that @Jens pointed out, you can also largely simplify your function. Assignments are comparatively more expensive in plpgsql than in other popular languages.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pit(pensja real)
  RETURNS real AS
$func$
DECLARE
   dochod real := 12 * pensja;
BEGIN
   IF dochod <= 85528 THEN
      RETURN dochod * 0.18 - 556.02;
   ELSE
      RETURN (dochod - 85528) * 0.32 + 14839;
   END IF;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```